# Rails test that method is called from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller function that calls a service and I want to test that the service is called with the right arguments.

```
def send_for_signature
  client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  external_documents = params[:document_ids].map{|id| ExternalDocument.find(id)}
  service = EsignGenieSendByTemplate.new(client: client, external_documents: external_documents, form_values: params[:form_values])
  result = service.process

  if result["result"] == "success"
    head 200
  else
    render json: result["error_description"], status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

How would I write my test to ensure that `EsignGenieSendByTemplate.new(client: client, external_documents: external_documents, form_values: params[:form_values])` is called correctly?

Comment: A note that `external_documents = params[:document_ids].map{|id| ExternalDocument.find(id)}` can be written as `external_documents = ExternalDocument.find(params[:document_ids])` to save a few SQL queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by adding a factory method to the service:

```
class EsignGenieSendByTemplate
  # ...
  def self.process(**kwargs)
    new(**kwargs).process
  end
end
```

This kind of code is boilerplate in almost any kind of service object and provides a better API between the service object and its consumers (like the controller).

This method should be covered by an example in your service spec.

```
describe '.process' do
  let(:options) do
    { client: 'A', external_documents: 'B', form_values: 'C' }
  end

  it "forwards its arguments" do
    expect(described_class).to recieve(:new).with(**options)
    EsignGenieSendByTemplate.process(**options)
  end

  it "calls process on the instance" do
    dbl = instance_double('EsignGenieSendByTemplate')
    allow(described_class).to recieve(:new).and_return(dbl) 
    expect(dbl).to recieve(:process)
    EsignGenieSendByTemplate.process(**options)
  end
end
```

Your controller should just call the factory method instead of instanciating  EsignGenieSendByTemplate:

```
def send_for_signature
  client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  # Just pass an array to .find instead of looping - this create a single 
  # db query instead of n+1
  external_documents = ExternalDocument.find(params[:document_ids])
  result = EsignGenieSendByTemplate.process(
    client: client, 
    external_documents: external_documents, 
    form_values: params[:form_values]
  )

  if result["result"] == "success"
    head 200
  else
    render json: result["error_description"], status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

This better API between the controller and service lets you set an expectation on the `EsignGenieSendByTemplate` class instead so you don't have to monkey around with `expect_any_instance` or stubbing the `.new` method.

```
it 'requests the signature' do
  expect(EsignGenieSendByTemplate).to receive(:process).with(client: 'A', external_documents: 'B', form_values: 'C')
  get :send_for_signature, params:  { ... }
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate this response.  Couple questions, 1) Should I define `dbl` in the `"forwards its arguments"` test the same way you did in the `"calls process on the instance"` test?  And 2) After defining `dbl` that way, the test fails and states: Failure/Error: new(**kwargs).process #<InstanceDouble(EsignGenieSendByTemplate) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :process with (no args)

Comment: Sorry that was a misstake on my part `.and_return(dbl)` was not supposed to be in the first example. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something called [expecting messages](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages#passing-positive-message-expectation).

I usually write something like this:

```
it 'requests the signature' do
  expect(EsignGenieSendByTemplate).to receive(:new).with(client: 'A', external_documents: 'B', form_values: 'C')
  get :send_for_signature, params:  { ... }
  expect(response.status).to have_http_status(:success)
end
```