# Globally mock method calling external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Background: I'm bringing to life a 6-year-old Rails project and haven't touched the framework since then. Thus, I'm re-learning many things.

I'm trying to understand the best approach to mock an API call that needs to be done synchronously. An **Order** has_one **Invoice**, and Invoice *must* get a reference from an external service. An Order is useless without an Invoice.

Below is a simple version of the application. The Order model is core to the application.

Open questions:

- Is the best practise to globally mock SDKs in spec_helper.rb? Which would contain my `allow_any_instance_of(InvoiceServiceSdk)`
- I have an Order factory, used almost everywhere in my tests. But I'm confused if I can loop in an Invoice factory as well. FactoryBot feels quite alien to me at the moment.

```rb
# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :invoice, autosave: true

  before_create :build_invoice

  def build_invoice
    self.invoice = Invoice.new
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/invoice.rb
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order

  before_create :generate

  def generate
    invoice_service = InvoiceServiceSdk.new
    self.external_id = invoice_service.fetch
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/invoice_service_sdk.rb
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

class InvoiceServiceSdk
  def fetch
    uri = URI('https://example.com/') # Real HTTP request
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64       # "ID" that API "provides"
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/models/order.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Order, type: :model do
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(InvoiceServiceSdk).to receive(:fetch).and_return('super random external invoice ID')
  end
  context "new order + invoice" do
    it {
      o = Order.new
      o.save
      expect(o.invoice.external_id).to eq 'super random external invoice ID'
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: You should narrow this down to a single question. `allow_any_instance_of` is considered a code smell and its use is not recommended by the RSpec team outside of legacy code.  You should create a factory method on your service object which can be stubbed instead. See this answer from a few days ago to a similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68993724/544825

Comment: Stubbing HTTP can be done with the  webmock and VCR gems.

Comment: @max I'm using WebMock and VCR throughout my testing. Is it smelly to Stub the request in spec_helper?

Comment: I would really encourage you to create a separate question regarding FactoryBot .

Comment: Factories pattern is new to me. I went with WebMocking the endpoint globally.

Comment: If you're talking about factory methods it's nothing fancy, it's really just a class metod that creates an instance of the class. You have already used tons of them like ".create"

Answer (score 0):

The [rspec-mocks documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) discourages the use of `allow_any_instance`:

- The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)
- Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.

You can avoid it completely by just adding a factory method to your service objects:

```
class MyService
  def intialize(**kwargs)
    @options = kwargs
  end

  def call
    do_something_awesome(@options[:foo])
  end

  def self.call(**kwargs)
    new(**kwargs).call
  end
end

allow(MyService).to recieve(:call).and_return([:foo, :bar, :baz])
```

> Is it smelly to Stub the request in spec_helper?

Not necissarily. You can avoid a bit of overhead by refactoring the code as indicated above and stubbing the factory method. It also makes it so that your stubs are not coupled to the inner workings of the service object.

I would be more worried about the fact that this code does one thing right by using a service object and then immediately cancels that out by calling it in a model callback.

Comment: I usually put HTTP calls into a seperate type of objects that I would call *API clients*  which just do HTTP and normalize responses which is the only object which is allowed to know about the external API. If you want to for example use an API and create a model instances out of it you would create both a service object and a client class (or multiple classes).